# oracle 10g ~ getting local user list

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, oracle10g, data-dictionary

In Oracle 11g, they have a column called `Authentication_Type` in the `dba_users` table, using which we can get the list of local users created using password with the simple following query:

```
select USERNAME from DBA_USERS where AUTHENTICATION_TYPE = 'PASSWORD'
```

My question is, how can I get the list of local users created by password in Oracle 10g?
In Oracle 10g the `dba_users` table doesn't have the `Authentication_Type` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `password` column. Local users will show an encrypted password. External ones will show `null`:

```
SELECT username
FROM   dba_users
WHERE  password IS NOT NULL
```